# Mutual SSL Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

I have client app which connects to server and the authentication is mutual ssl.
I am trying to setup mutual ssl but it is failing with below exception.
I am giving rest call using resttemplate.

```
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 264
http-nio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
[Raw write]: length = 269
http-nio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
http-nio-8080-exec-3, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
%% Invalidated: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]
http-nio-8080-exec-3, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, description = unexpected_message
http-nio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-3, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
http-nio-8080-exec-3, called closeSocket()
```

the flow for mutual sll client hello then serverhello then certificateverify then client cert has CA sent by server after that key exchange is also successfuly but at last step certificateverify it fails.
I am not sure what is wrong here, could anyone plleaese help out?

Comment: Is this the client or the server log?

Comment: it is client log

Answer (score 1):

After lot of time invested, I discovered that , wrong client alias was getting passed.